# Set {{ content }} in Jekyll included template via nested layouts

Tags: jekyll, liquid

This may be too complicated and there may be a better design, so I'm open to suggestions.

Essentially I have a default-page.html that look something like

...
   
        {{ content }}
   
   ...

I want a posts page where the content is going to be a for-loop over all posts.

So this posts page can call the default-page setting the content to its own content -- how?

- Can the posts.html itself have a layout feature, creating a nested layout?
- Is the best way to through everything into a captured variable? This seems complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking it. `posts.html` or `posts/index.html` can be an HTML file, that uses Liquid, that has a `layout` on top. Calling liquid does not preclude a file from using a layout.

I am not sure whether nested layouts are also possible but the syntax certainly would be identical.